# Extension Stop working when I open a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
let Refresher = async () => {
  if (cond) {
    let min = Math.floor(Math.abs(parseFloat(Number(minNum.value))));
    let max = Math.floor(Math.abs(parseFloat(Number(maxNum.value))));
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    badgeText = random;
    divTEST.innerHTML = `<h2>Wait For ${random} Seconds</h2>`;
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true
    });
    myTabId = tab.id;
    chrome.tabs.reload(parseInt(myTabId));
    setTimeout(Refresher, random * 1000);
  }
};
```

Hello,
I was creating my first simple page refresher extension, and everything works fine but the problem is when I open a new tab the page refresher stop working.
I want it to work if I open a new tab just like the other extension which are available on the chrome store.

I write this code in popup.js and the background.js file is empty.

Thank You!

Comment: How do you run this function?

Comment: I'm calling this function in the event listener
///In event Listener 
`
buttonDiv.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  if (minNum.value && maxNum.value) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.target.classList.contains("start")) {

      e.target.disabled = true;

      cond = true;

      console.log("start");

//*Here it is*

      Refresher();

//*Here it is*

      setBadgeTxt();

    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("stop")) {

      console.log("stop");

      clearAll();

`